# Border в row при наведении

Tags: css, html, table, border

Здравствуйте. Есть вот такая табличка, сверстанная на дивах:

```css
        .table{
            display:table;
            width:100%;
        }

        .row{
            display:table-row;
        }

        .col{
            display:table-cell;
        }
 
      .col:hover {
   border-bottom:2px solid #22a1c4;
       }
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">Сезонность</div>
  <div class="col">Летние</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">Диаметр</div>
  <div class="col">13</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">Профиль</div>
  <div class="col">60</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

И мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши подчеркивался весь ряд, а не только один столбец. Пыталась давать стиль классу row, но тогда border совсем пропадал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо hover ставить так:

```
.row:hover .col {...}
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}

.row:hover .col {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #22a1c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Сезонность</div>
    <div class="col">Летние</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Диаметр</div>
    <div class="col">13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Профиль</div>
    <div class="col">60</div>
  </div>
</div>
```